# Separar listagens de um objeto para cada objeto do tipo de uma outra classe

Tags: java, algoritmo, regra-de-negócio

Boa Noite.
A minha dúvida é em relação ao algorítmo do meu projeto, estou tentando fazer uma aplicação aonde cada Cliente possa fazer vários pedidos mas cada pedido pertence a um Cliente diferente. Ainda recordo daquela lógica do "um para muitos" e da agregação aonde cada cliente tem um pedido também. Só que eu não sei como fazer isso na interface gráfica do programa para separar cada pedido por um cliente, como eu faria a lógica mais ou menos na aplicação? Obrigado.

Comment: Acredito que declarar Cliente com o atributo de List<Pedidos> e cada Pedido possui um atributo idCliente para identificar o cliente é suficiente.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer assim como você disse Daniela, talvez o problema é que fiz esse teste no main() ele acabou até dando certo mas quando fui dividir os clientes em uma form acabei não conseguindo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Interface Gráfica

Na Interface Gráfica você pode fazer uma **Tabela de Clientes**, com colunas como "Nome do Cliente", "Quantidade de Pedidos", etc. Ou seja, cada Linha com um Cliente diferente.

Ao clicar em uma Linha desta **Tabela de Clientes** você abre outra Tela com outra Tabela; esta segunda Tela terá as informações do Cliente e, inclusive, terá uma **Tabela de Pedidos** deste Cliente, com Colunas como "Quantidades de Itens no Pedido", "Data do Pedido", etc. Todos os Pedidos feitos por este Cliente estarão nesta Tabela.

Ao Clicar em uma Linha da **Tabela de Pedidos** você pode abrir em outra Tela (ou abrir em uma "Caixa Sanfona" [flutuante ou não] abaixo da Linha) uma Tabela com os Itens que estão neste Pedido, onde as Colunas seriam "Nome do Produto", "Quantidade", "Valor Unitário", "Valor Total", etc.

Veja um Exemplo que criei aqui da Tela com os Dados do Cliente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que você precisará de muito mais coisas, como formas de pagamento, parcelamento, etc. Isso é só uma ideia de layou.

### Design de Classes (lógica da aplicação):

Você pode criar uma Classe "Cliente" que terá uma Lista de Objetos "Pedido", cada Objeto "Pedido" terá Lista de Objetos "ItemPedido", e, cada Objeto "ItemPedido" terá:

- UM (Exatamente UM) Objeto "Item" (o Produto) que já possui o "Cód." dele e o Nome dele;
- A Quantidade (`int` com as unidades compradas neste Pedido);
- O "Valor Unitário", o "Valor Total" (que é "quantidade * valorUnitario"), e o "Valor Pago".

Lembre-se de usar  [“Money and Currency API”](http://www.matera.com/br/2015/09/14/dinheiro-e-moedas-com-java-use-a-java-money-api/) ou pelo menos `BigDecimal` para lidar com dinheiro, não use `double` para isto (veja [aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/java-bigdecimal-trabalhando-com-mais-precisao/30286) porque usar BigDecimal ao invés de Double para lidar com dinheiro).

Comment: Isso me ajudou bem a clarear a idéia em separar cada lista de pedidos por cada cliente!! Eu não tinha conhecimento antes dessa divisão e ficava confuso em listar todos os pedidos de todos os clientes e após efetuar uma pesquisa de um cliente pelo id para depois gerar o valor total mas não sei se assim também seria certo.. ajudou a resolver minha dúvida!!